# How to prevent multiple logins using the same username and password in Spring security

Tags: spring-security, restful-authentication, multiple-login

I have implemented spring security with a restful API using spring boot and everything work perfectly.
I wan't to prevent multiple login with the same username and password from the same client. how can I do that ?

Comment: @dur yes, the user can login from different clients

Comment: No they don't have fixed IP address, I mean I can't identify clients

Answer (score 0):

The only approach that I can think of is to identify the clients by their IP and then only allow one login per client. Here‘s a tutorial on how to block accounts after several login failed attempts from the same IP / client.

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts

Maybe it could give you an idea on how to solve your problem.

Please be aware that there are some problems coming with this, like dynamic IP addresses (the user gets a new IP address after disconnecting) and if more than one user uses the same proxy and therefore all of them have the same IP address.

Comment: I mean I want to prevent logged in users from login again
but users can be logged in from two different computer
the restriction would be only from the same browser

Comment: i do not know why you would achieve this, but you could maybe go for the IP of the client.

Comment: I simple don't want authenticated users from re-authenticate

Comment: i‘m aware of that, but as I wrote: this is all i could think of to come close to what op wants with not too much configuration effort..